# Full Width Background Image

Tags: css

I have an issue with the background image for a header.
I'm creating a non-responsive website with a minimum width of 960px for the content area.
When the screen is 960px or larger, the background image in the header goes across the entire screen.
When the screen is smaller than 960px, the background image in the header starts to shrink to the left, leaving white space on the right side when you scroll to the right.
Is there a way to:

1. Not make the screen scroll so far that white space appears?
   and/or
2. Make the background image appear as far across the screen as scrolling allows?

Here is my CSS:

```
header {
        display: block; /* So that all browsers render it */
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 300px;
        background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Swallow_flying_drinking.jpg") no-repeat top center;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }

.subWrapper {
        width: 960px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        padding: 50px 50px;
        background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    }
```

And my HTML:

```
<body>
        <header>
        <div class="subWrapper">        
        </div>
        </header>
</body>
```

Please see this JSfiddle for an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/QrMV4/2/

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
/* This is what makes the background image rescale based
     on the container's size */
  background-size: cover;
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/QrMV4/3/)

Comment: I think my title might be misleading and apologize for the mis-communication. I'm asking how to get rid of white space next to the header on screens smaller than 960px, not how to rescale the background image based on the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right...

Insert:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

In `header`

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the background-attachment: fixed to scroll and put width on header as you mean to have the header on center, replace the widt:960px of subWrapper to 860px on subwrapper and remove margin-left:auto and marging-right: auto...

You can have a look on jsFiddle to

http://jsfiddle.net/9YuW6/

```
header {
    display: block; /* So that all browsers render it */
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 300px;
    width:960px;
    background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Swallow_flying_drinking.jpg") no-repeat top center;
    /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
}
```